# JavaScript new formData().append is not working for uploaded files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In my Reactjs application, I'm sending an uploaded file with some data to API with AXIOS. After a work around, I setup the following code and trying to send it to the back end. However I can't send a file to the API. **After input a file and send it to the API, the Request Payload in Network tab shows the uploaded file variable as Empty {} always**. How can I solve this?

```
uploadFile(event) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);

        const files = [
            {
                name: "n1",
                description: "d1",
                file: data,
                business_file_type: 1
            }
        ];
        const project_id = 1;

        const allData = { files, project_id }

        API.post('project/files/upload', allData)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                console.log("success", data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
            })
    }

<input className={classes.input} type="file" id="fileInput" name="ifile" onChange={this.uploadFile} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: pass everything in form data.

```
data.append('file', file);

const files_related_data = [
    {
        name: "n1",
        description: "d1",
        business_file_type: 1
    }
];
const project_id = 1;
data.append('files_related_data', files_related_data);
data.append('project_id', project_id);

const allData = data;
```